# Double spacing between figures in List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, line-spacing

I am using a specific class in LaTeX to write my thesis. I am required to double space between all my figures in the List of Figures. At the moment it is single spaced within a chapter and double spaced between chapters. I was wondering how I could edit it?
This is what is used currently :

```
% LIST OF FIGURES
%

% Single-space list of figures, add it to the table of contents.

\def\listoffigures{%

  \@restonecolfalse%

  \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\fi%

  \newpage% 

  \centerline{\expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{\listfigurename}}%

  \bigskip%
  \phantomsection%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{frontmatter}{\protect\numberline{}\listfigurename }%


  %This group overloads \numberline to output ``Figure 1.3'' instead of ``1.3''
  \begingroup%

    \let\ORIG@numberline\numberline%

    \renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{%

      \ORIG@numberline{\figurename~##1:}}%

    {\ssp\@starttoc{lof}}%

    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi%

  \endgroup %
  }

\newlength{\@figurelength}
\settowidth{\@figurelength}{\figurename }
% Magic value, but consistent with the standard figure length
\addtolength{\@figurelength}{2.8em}
\def\l@figure{\normalfont\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{\@figurelength}}
```

How do I edit it for double spacing?

Answer (score 1):

There are packages `titletoc` and `tocloft` that let you fiddle with the styles and layout of TOC, LOF etc. Good for a rainy weekend.

For a quick and dirty hack, just use package setspace, and shove your LOF inside a doublespacing environment:

```
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

...

\begin{doublespacing}
\listoffigures
\end{doublespacing}

...
```

I attach no ouput, but I just checked on a document of my own that it works.

Update: If `setspace` doesn't cut it, maybe this will help you:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cftbeforefigskip{\baselineskip}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This didn't seem to work for me for some reason. What I did was change the {\ssp@starttoc{lof}} to {\dsp@starttoc{lof}}, unfortunately this double spaced the entire list of figures (including the captions of the figures) instead of making entries within the same chapter alone double spaced.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest giving `titletoc` a try. I will update my answer with some details.

Comment: `tocloft` maybe more expedient after all - see updated answer.